# Validar formulario

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Necesito validar los campos de un formulario con jquery y ya había echo unos pero este formulario esta escrito en php y no me sale,Este es el código del formulario

```
<form name='frmUpdEspecialidades' id='frmUpdEspecialidades' action='qryEspecialidades.php' method='POST'>
                <table align='center' width='430'>
                    <tr height='100'>
                        <td colspan='2' align='center'>
                            <b>Modificando especialidades</b>
                            <input type='hidden' id='hdnOpc' name='hdnOpc'>
                            <input type='hidden' id='hdnId' name='hdnId'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>$id</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Clave</td>
                        <td><input type='text' id='txtClave' name='txtClave' value='$clave'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td><input type='text' id='txtNombre' name='txtNombre' value='$nombre'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2' align='center'>
                        <input type='button' id='btnGrabar' name='btnGrabar' value='Grabar' style='width:100px' onClick='enviar(\"modificar\")'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

y este es el código de jquery que estoy usando

```
function validarFormulario(){
    $("#frmUpdEspecialidades").validate();
}
```

ya mande llamar el url de jquery y aun así no funciona me sigue registrando los datos aun que existan campos vacíos

Comment: Pude poner todo el javascript de la función `validarFormulario(){}`

Comment: que mal le ha hecho jquery a javascript..

Comment: @Ale este fue un ejemplo que use y dice que solo con esa linea al momento de que se de click al boton grabar mandara el mensaje diciendo que existen campos vacios ya que estoy usando la libreria de jquery validate.js

Comment: @EduardoSebastian yo prefiero el jquery al javascript D: Hablando del tema, prueba con el atributo "required", parece ser que ese plug-in hace uso de ellos para validar los formularios

Comment: Para mi jquery es una herramienta para el trabajo fácil

Answer (score 0):

Para una validación básica utilizando el plugin de jquery [validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) es necesario que los inputs que desea validar tengan la etiqueta `required` de la siguiente manera

```
<input type='text' id='txtClave' name='txtClave' value='$clave' required>
```

El javascript debería verse así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmUpdEspecialidades").validate();
});
```

Para ver más detalle del uso del plugin puede ver este [ejemplo](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/index.html)